# How do I use inputs.property on a Gradle task, but with a closure for a value?

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to add an installer builder to my build configuration and I'm having a little trouble getting task inputs set up properly.  I have the configuration split into a separate .gradle file and I add it to my project by doing the following.

```groovy
project.ext.i4jArgs = [ "--verbose" ]
apply from: rootProject.projectDir.absolutePath + "/gradle/install4j.gradle"
```

To build the installers I'm calling a command line tool via `exec`.  Almost everything is based on convention, but I want to optionally add a couple arguments / switches to the command from my main build file.  I do it using the `project.ext.i4jArgs` property (above).

If I set the `project.ext.i4jArgs` property before applying my `install4j.gradle` file, I can use the following for inputs and everything seems to work.

```groovy
inputs.property("i4jArgs", project.ext.has('i4jArgs') ? project.ext.i4jArgs : null)
```

However, if I apply my `install4j.gradle` file first and set the `project.ext.i4jArgs` property second, the `project.ext.i4jArgs` property is always `null` when I'm declaring inputs in my task (obviously).  The API for `TaskInputs` [(here)](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskInputs.html#property%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) says I can pass a closure as a value.  Is there a way I can use a closure to delay the evaluation of the `project.ext.i4jArgs` long enough to guarantee it's been initialized?  I though the following would work, but the closure never gets called.

```groovy
inputs.property("i4jArgs", {
    project.afterEvaluate {
        println "has args ${project.ext.has('i4jArgs')}"
        project.ext.has('i4jArgs') ? project.ext.i4jArgs : null
    }
})
```

I know writing a plugin that supports all the configuration I want might be a better option for the specific example I've given, but I'd like to figure out what I'm misunderstanding here anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would remove `project.afterEvaluate` in the first closure. This is for adding a closure that gets executed after the project has been configured.

What is actually going on is when gradle resolves the inputs, it calls the first closure, which then calls `project.afterEvaluate`, which adds a closure to the list that will be called when the project is done configuring... which will never be called because it is now in the execution phase.

Comment: That makes sense.  Now that I think about it, it's fairly obvious the inputs and outputs evaluation would need to be done after the configuration phase is complete.  Thanks for the explanation.